# crcmod's xorOut parameter does not behave the same as manually xor'ing

Tags: python, crc, crc32

`crcmod`'s [documentation](http://crcmod.sourceforge.net/crcmod.html) states:

"xorOut – Final value to XOR with the calculated CRC value. Used by some CRC algorithms. Defaults to zero."

I expected from that description that setting that parameter to a non-zero number (say, 0xFFFFFFFF) was equivalent to taking the CRC with parameter zero and then xor'ing it with that number using the `^` operator.

That's not the behavior I see. What did I assume wrong? What's the actual behavior of the xorOut parameter?

Here's some code straight from my interactive interpreter. I expected the last line to be True.

```
>>> import crcmod
>>> crc32_func_noxor = crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x104c11db7, initCrc=0, rev=True, xorOut=0)
>>> crc32_func_xor = crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x104c11db7, initCrc=0, rev=True, xorOut=0xffffffff)
>>> crc32_func_noxor('12345678'.decode('hex'))^0xffffffff==crc32_func_xor('12345678'.decode('hex'))
False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation:

> initCrc – Initial value used to start the CRC calculation. This
>   initial value should be the initial shift register value, reversed if
>   it uses a reversed algorithm, and then XORed with the final XOR value.
>   That is equivalent to the CRC result the algorithm should return for a
>   zero-length string. Defaults to all bits set because that starting
>   value will take leading zero bytes into account. Starting with zero
>   will ignore all leading zero bytes.

This means that if you don't specify `initCrc`, it will initialize the register to the the final XOR value, `xorOut`.  If you want to have the effect of *only* exclusive-oring the result, then you can set `initCrc` to `xorOut`.

Comment: Redefining the "-xor" function with initCrc equal to xorOut makes it behave as I was expecting. The example comparison now returns True. Thanks!